# Toogle button not updating state properly

Tags: reactjs, sidebar

I have a button that I am using to toggle my sidebar in react application. The toggle button works fine for first two toggle states than it repeats the state twice for third time.
This is how I am toggling state from child component to parent:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Header extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
             toggle: false
        }
    }

    toggleSidebar = () => {

        this.setState({
            toggle : !this.state.toggle
        });
        console.log(this.state.toggle)
        this.props.getToggleState(this.state.toggle);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                 <button style={{width: '60px'}} onClick={this.toggleSidebar}>Toogle</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}



export default class App extends Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      toggleVal:''
    }
  }

  getData = (val) => {
   this.setState({
     toggleVal: val
   })
}

  render(){
    let toggleConst = '';
    if(this.state.toggleVal){
      toggleConst = (
                <Router>
                <div style={{display: 'flex', backgroundColor: '#ccc', height: '100%', flexDirection:'row'}}>
                  <div style={{flexDirection:'column'}}>
                    <Header getToggleState={this.getData}/>
                      <Routes/>
                    <Footer/>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </Router>
      )
    }
    else{
      toggleConst = (
                <Router>
                <div style={{display: 'flex', backgroundColor: '#ccc', height: '100%', flexDirection:'row'}}>
                  <SideNav toggleVal={this.state.toggleVal}/>
                  <div style={{flexDirection:'column'}}>
                    <Header getToggleState={this.getData}/>
                      <Routes/>
                    <Footer/>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </Router>
      )
    }
    return (
      toggleConst
    );
  }

}
```

Toggling the button hides/open the sidebar perfectly but it stuck on state when gets 'false' as twice. 
This is how state console goes:

[image]

I am not able to find the problem here. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Several pieces seems to be missing like SideNav, Routes and Footer components. Could you add the full code please?

Comment: @darmis https://repl.it/repls/UsefulLimitedResource Here

Comment: is that the source of true? the code there seems different from the sample code in your question, for instance this state value ` toggleVal: '' ` in the App component is different here and there.

Comment: Sorry I pasted edited code. Here is original https://repl.it/repls/IllustriousPhonyAddresses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router} from "react-router-dom";
import Header from './Header';
import Sidebar from './Sidebar'

export default class App extends Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  
    this.state = {
      toggleVal: false
    }
  }
  
  getData = (val) => {
   
   this.setState({
     toggleVal: val
   });
}

  render(){
    console.log("called.....123...",this.state.toggleVal)
    if(this.state.toggleVal){
      return (
                <Router>
                <div style={{display: 'flex', backgroundColor: '#ccc', height: '100%', flexDirection:'row'}}>
                <Sidebar toggleVal={this.state.toggleVal}/>
                  <div style={{flexDirection:'column'}}>
                    <Header getToggleState={this.getData} />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </Router>
      )
    }
    else{
      return (
                <Router>
                <div style={{display: 'flex', backgroundColor: '#ccc', height: '100%', flexDirection:'row'}}>
                  <Sidebar toggleVal={this.state.toggleVal}/>
                  <div style={{flexDirection:'column'}}>
                    <Header getToggleState={this.getData}/>

                  </div>
                </div>
              </Router>
      )
    }
  }
  
}
```

> Header.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Header extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    
        this.state = {
             toggle: false
        }
    }


    toggleSidebar = () => {

        this.setState({
          toggle: !this.state.toggle
        },()=>{
            // console.log(this.state.toggle)
            this.props.getToggleState(this.state.toggle);
        });
       
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                 <button onClick={()=>this.toggleSidebar(this.state.toggle)}>Toogle</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

> Sidebar.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";


export default class Sidebar extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <>
            {
                this.props.toggleVal &&
                    <div className="sidebar_container">
                        <nav className="nav_container">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <NavLink to="/" activeClassName="active" exact={true}>Dashboard</NavLink>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <NavLink to="/user" activeClassName="active">User PRofile</NavLink>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <NavLink to="/register" activeClassName="active">Register</NavLink>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
            }
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

https://repl.it/repls/IncredibleLinedCgi

This Will Work for You

Comment: But how do I reflect that updation outside the setState(), so that sidebar toggles everytime properly.

Comment: @bubble-cord i have edited the answer please check it

Comment: I tried your approach but it still goes toggling in same way. It takes two times 'false' state and then true and keeps  on repeating like that.

Comment: . It takes two times 'false' state and then true, this scenario arise when you click or when you reload it

Comment: So even if this happens, It is not the correct approach to toggle the sidebar, isn't it?

Comment: I have edited the answer, can you please check it, now it would work for you,

Comment: check the below link i have run the code and its working

Comment: https://repl.it/repls/UsefulLimitedResource If you can have a look at this link. I followed yours. Still problem persist.

Comment: @bubble-cord i have run the code and now its working please have a look https://repl.it/repls/IncredibleLinedCgi and edited by code

Answer (score 0):

Change this part of the code:

```
this.setState({
        toggle : !this.state.toggle
    });
```

To this:

```
this.setState(prev => {
        return { toggle : !prev.toggle }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call getToggleState inside your setState callback in order to use proper state as argument

```
this.setState(prevState => {
  this.props.getToggleState(!prevState.toggle);
  return { toggle: !prevState.toggle };
});
```

Despite this solution, it's better if you don't keep duplicate state in child component `<Header />` as conditional render is Parent duty.

Answer (score 0):

This could be much simpler in my opinion.

> 1. Define the state on the parent component App `ìsToggled`
> 2. Call from the child component Header via callback `this.props.onToggle()`
> 3. Use conditional rendering on parent component `{this.state.isToggled && <Sidebar/>}`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from "react-router-dom";
import Header from './Header';
import Sidebar from './Sidebar'

export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isToggled: false
        }
    };

    onToggle = () => {
        this.setState({
            isToggled: !this.state.isToggled
        });
        console.log(this.state.isToggled);
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <div style={{display: 'flex', backgroundColor: '#ccc', height: '100%', flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                    <div style={{flexDirection: 'column'}}>
                        <Header onToggle={this.onToggle}/>
                    </div>
                    {this.state.isToggled && <Sidebar/>}
                </div>
            </Router>
        )
    }
}
```

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

export default class Header extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={() => {
                    this.props.onToggle()
                }}>Toggle
                </button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {NavLink} from "react-router-dom";

export default class Sidebar extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="sidebar_container">
                <nav className="nav_container">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <NavLink to="/" activeClassName="active" exact={true}>Dashboard</NavLink>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <NavLink to="/user" activeClassName="active">User PRofile</NavLink>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <NavLink to="/register" activeClassName="active">Register</NavLink>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```